# Why the convoluted plan to access Haldora in Absolution Gap?

Tags: revelation-space

I read the Revelation Space novels, plus Chasm City, several years ago.  One of the major plot points of the final book Absolution Gap has never really made sense to me.

As best I can recall, and augmented by Wikipedia, the situation was as follows:

The Nostalgia for Infinity arrives at Haldora, fleeing the Inhibitors.  The crew suspects that the strange phenomenon of Haldora occasionally blinking out of existence might provide a way of dealing with the Inhibitors.  Unfortunately, access to the planet is controlled by the religious zealot Quaiche, who maintains a moving cathedral on one of Haldora's moons.  The crew of the Nostalgia sends the young girl Aura to the moon to be raised as an orphan.  There, she eventually grows up and (unknowingly) infiltrates Quaiche's cult.

That seems like a reasonable if complicated plan on the face of it.  But during its flight, the Nostalgia made use of far-future weapons to contend with and drive off the Inhibitors, a race which is technologically millions (or was it billions?) of years ahead of humanity.  The Inhibitors are actively wiping out humanity.  Time is of the essence, one would think.

So why doesn't the Nostalgia employ its super-weapons to fend off any interference from Quaiche and investigate Haldora immediately?  Why give the Inhibitors another decade or so to wipe out humanity unimpeded?

Comment: Wiping out a race seems like the sort of thing you want to do right rather than do quick.

Comment: Perhaps, but the crew of the Nostalgia couldn't really know that for certain.  And in any case, why kowtow to the demands of a religious cultist with vastly inferior technological capability?